# PHP numbers and text in a string

Tags: php, string, random

I'm trying to get `$randpros` to be something like this 0.15 but I got a problem `$randpros = 0.$randpri;` won't work.

Here is the code I've tried:

```
$randpri = rand(5,15);
$randpros = 0.$randpri;
```

Is there another way to add 0. in front of `$randpros`?

Comment: [str_pad()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php), [sprintf()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: Why not `$randpros = 0.01*(rand(5,15));`?

Comment: I think this is not working as intended cause you're trying to concatenate a string to an integer. So you have to decide if you want it to be a string or an integer. See the answers posted below.

Comment: Can you please clarify if you want a *number* between 0.05 and 0.15, or one of the following *strings*: 0.5, 0.6, ..., 0.9, 0.10, 0.11, ..., 0.15

Comment: `"0." .$randpri` - many ways to do this and as stated below; depends what you want to do with this. You'll need to elaborate on your question.

Answer (score 3):

Do [plain math](https://eval.in/445277)!

Case *"I want to pass a random integer as float point to zero"*:

```
$randpros = 0.01*(rand(5,15));
```

Case *"I want a random integer to pose as float point to zero"*:

```
$i = rand(5,15);
$randpros = $i < 10 ? (0.1*$i) : (0.01*$i);
```

Comment: Uhm, I'm not sure if OP wants 0.07 if `rand` returns `7`, or 0.7 like the other answer

Comment: @Federico It's up to OP's needs. He can even have an `if` for that, but surely string-int concatenation is **not** the best one.

Comment: Yeah, I love "math" ;-) especially when things "add up".

Answer (score 2):

use double quotes as follows:

```
$randpri = rand(5,15);
$randpros = "0.{$randpri}";
```

Comment: This would result in a String. If that's intended, this is great. If you want to perform math on it later, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Cast it as a Float:

```
$randpros = floatval("0." . $randpri);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in need of a random number format 0.xx

```
<?php

  echo ( rand( 0, 99 ) / 100 );

?>
```

Comment: Alan Machado already gave the same response

Comment: well, i wouldnt say that unless its something ive missed...

Comment: Maybe you've missed that 1*0.01 == 1/100

Comment: No, but my example was not a copy of your answer, aka not the same response